# Regular Expression for Alphanumeric, Phone, Email, special eg: "[A-C,@#!]"

Tags: regex

I would like to have a regular expression that checks if a string contains only Upper and Lowercase letters, Numbers,Phone, Email, special eg: "[A-C,@#!]"

Can i have all these in a single regexp?

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you want the string to contain.  What do you mean by "contains only ... Phone, Email, special ..."  I can't tell if you want to filter by character or whether you want some higher-level structure too.

Comment: I'm looping inside a form to validate. There are many fields and these are the type of data that they can have.

Comment: `(  email regex | phone regex | special char regex)` Something like this?

Comment: @Mr_Green yes exactly

Comment: Do you mean some fields are phone numbers, some are emails and other are just strings with certain character restrictions?  And do you know which kind of field each one should be before you parse it?

Comment: I don't know which field is which. That's why I'm trying like this

Comment: Honestly, I don't recommend that.  anyway if you want to use then join the regex's provided by paulsm4 in the below post. keep them in brackets with `|` as separation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [RegexLib.com](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?categoryId=7&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

- e-mail: `\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b`
- Phone#: `^[0-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$`

And no, it's unlikely you can concoct a "one size fits all regex" for every one of the very different scenarios you mentioned.

Comment: My question is can i have all my requirements in one regex